# Windows Forms FolderBrowserDialog hangs the application

Tags: c#, winforms, folderbrowserdialog

With winforms, when I right click on a folder or try to delete a folder within the `FolderBrowserDialog` the window becomes irresponsive and I've to force-close it.

Here's the code:

```
private void btnOpenFileDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = txtBoxLog.Text;
    folderBrowserDialog1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
    if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
    {
        txtBoxLog.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you given in txtBoxLog.Text?

Comment: I set it to C:\temp\. The folder exists and its path is correctly opened in the dialog.

Comment: try programattically creating :   FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog();
 instead of using the FolderBrowserDialog control from toolbox.

Comment: Nothing to do. I'm now trying to extend the class for a workaround.

Comment: Nevermind: my whole system has this issue. Is another type of problem.
The control behave as expected. Thanks for your help though.
(should I mark this question in some way or post this in the solution maybe?)

Comment: As your like :) cheers!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was system wide, so the control was correctly behaving in an incorrect way (irony).